# Symlink to application in mac

Tags: macos, path, symlink

I created a symlink to sublime text editor like this in my bin folder:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2 ~/bin/sublime
```

I exported the bin folder to the PATH in .bash_profile like this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

When I try to open sublime by typing sublime in terminal i get:

```
xxxxx@xxxx-Air:~$ sublime
2015-08-06 08:05:16.238 sublime[2495:355442] Sparkle Error: the bundle being updated at {
} has no CFBundleIdentifier! This will cause preference read/write to not work properly.
```

On the other hand, when I try to type the full path like this it works fine:

```
xxxxx@xxxxx-Air:~$ /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

Is there something wrong with my symlink?

Comment: I have the same problem. Don't know why the symlink technique isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

To launch Sublime Text 2 from the Mac OS X Terminal, create a symlink to `SharedSupport/bin/subl` instead of `MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2`:

`ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ~/bin/subl`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.  When you did the `ln -s` command, you didn't link all the way to the binary file for the app.  So you got a wacky / unexpected response instead of launching that editor.

Try doing this instead:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2 ~/bin/sublime
```

Comment: I actually had the right path set already, I now changed it in my post. I STILL HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM..

Comment: Try setting an alias in your shell (are you really using bash, or are you using tcsh, which is the default MacOS shell).  For tcsh, you can test it out via something like "`alias launchsublime /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2`".  Then start the app via `launchsublime`.  Let me know if you get the same error as before.

Comment: The alias works fine, thanks.. I would be nice to know why the link didn't work though